# How do you include ampersands in URLs for adb shell am start?

Tags: android, adb

Using

```
$ adb shell am start some://url
```

I can launch URLs using activity manager.  However if I include multiple URL parameters, all but the first parameter gets stripped out.

Example:

```
$ adb shell am start http://www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2
```

Returns:

```
$ Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.example.com?param1=1 }
```

and param2 disappears as anything after an ampersand gets ignored.  I'm wondering if there's some encoding/escape character for the & that will prevent this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

use escape character `\`:

```
$ adb shell am start "http://www.example.com?param1=1\&param2=2"
```

Comment: Unfortunately with platform tools version 21 there is a bug where the URL will get truncated after the first ampersand, even if you escape it. Please see this issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=76026

Comment: The workaround is to send: `$ adb shell am start "http://www.example.com?param1=1%26param2=2"`

Comment: Do anyone knows how to include the plus symbol and/or where to get the list of characters that needs to be escaped by any chance?

Answer (score 24):

The following format seems to work. Note the quotes format `'` `"`:

`$ adb shell am start -d '"http://www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2"'`

Comment: I wonder if this ought to be the accepted answer, as it seems much more preferable to having to escape every single ampersand in an already constructed link.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution does not work because of a bug in the android build tools which you can track here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76026 . A workaround is the below:

```
echo 'am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n <your package>/<broadcast-receiver> --es "referrer" "utm_source=test_source&utm_medium=test_medium&utm_term=test_term&utm_content=test_content&utm_campaign=test_name";exit'|adb shell
```

To integrate it in gradle you can use the commandLine statement

```
commandLine "bash","-c","echo ..."
```

Comment: Thank you for that! This is the proper way to test INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have already posted a workaround here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76026

So, here is the recipe that involves instrumentation.
Register a BroadcastReceiver within the instrumentation that listens to action com.example.action.VIEW.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.action.VIEW");
intentFilter.addDataScheme("myschema");
intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
Context.registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), intentFilter);
```

Replace ampersand with %26 (use can replace it with anything you want) and send an intent com.example.action.VIEW.
Once received intent BroadcastReceiver converts %26 back to ampersand and sends a new intent with desired action to your app.

```
public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.getDataString().replaceAll("%26", "&")));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Basically it acts as a BroadcastReceiver proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the `am...` command!
Something like the following should work (if it doesn't, try double-quote):

```
adb shell 'am start http://www.example.com?param1=1&param2=2'
```