# Android Intent Data Uri Query Parameter

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to launch my app using an intent like this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_scheme://my_host?queryParam1=QueryParam1&queryParam2=QueryParam2"
```

(I have registered for the data intent filter with scheme "my_app_scheme" and host "my_host")

But when I do

`getIntent().getData()`

all I get is the URI

`"my_scheme://my_host?queryParam1=QueryParam1"`

Only the first ever query param is set in the `getIntent().getData()`. Do you know why that might be? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try it by escaping the ampersand '&' using a '\'

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_scheme://my_host?queryParam1=QueryParam1\&queryParam2=QueryParam2"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all. I am getting the following out put on KitKat and Lollipop devices --

    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "my_scheme://my_host?queryParam1=QueryParam1\&queryParam2=QueryParam2"                                      
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=my_scheme://my_host?queryParam1=QueryParam1\ }

Comment: Turns out there's a bug with platform tools version 21. OP here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615841/how-do-you-include-ampersands-in-urls-for-adb-shell-am-start